# You are too smart for your own good - Meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does it mean when someone says "you are too smart for your own good"?

Comment: It can mean different things in different contexts (and this is true for just about every question asked here about the meaning of a word or a phrase).

Comment: [Why would someone say "you're too smart for your own good"?](https://www.quora.com/Why-would-someone-say-youre-too-smart-for-your-own-good)

Comment: Related: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+too+clever+by+half

Answer (score 2):

This phrase acknowledges a person's intelligence or knowledge while characterizing their lack of tact in using it.

It could be said about someone who constantly corrects their boss about minor details, for example. The person is technically correct, but might actually be hurting themselves professionally by bringing up many insignificant issues. The person is very smart, but is applying it in a way that's counter-productive. A less smart person might avoid this problem. Hence, the person is too smart for their own good.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that the person is overconfident or is a (or acts like a) know-it-all person and his knowledge is somehow hurting or working against him.

When people say this to you, it could mean that you are smart, but correcting other people would put you in their negative light.